# Node.js - Sending file with Axios POST

Tags: javascript, node.js, post, axios

I'm trying to send a PDF to a website using the Axios library on Node JS. The site gives an example that works perfectly if I use CURL:

```
curl -F "file=@test.pdf" https://my.hiddenwebsite.com/upload
```

But if I try to replicate the HTTP request using Axios it gives me an error FILE_NOT_PROVIDED with code 400. The following is the code that I tried to execute.

```
  let form = new FormData();
  let stream = fs.createReadStream(path.join(__dirname, "test.pdf"));
  form.append("file", stream);

  let formHeaders = form.getHeaders();

  const request_config = {
    headers: {
      ...formHeaders,
    },
  };

  axios
    .post("https://my.hiddenwebsite.com/upload", form, request_config)
    .then((res) => {
      console.log(res.data);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err.response.data);
    });
```

If someone could give me a hint on what I'm doing wrong, that would be great.

Comment: `createReadStream` returns a Stream, not a file. Perhaps [`readfilesync`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_path_options) serves you better

Comment: Your code works for me against a test server. I wonder if your server expects a specific filename? Could it be expecting something other than "file"?

Comment: @AndreNuechter I tried just now, that doesn't work either, same error

Comment: @TerryLennox I'm not really an expert on CURL, I don't use it that much, but I thought that that "file=@text.pdf" meant that the server wants a file with filename "file". Am I wrong?

Comment: Apologies, @Sosnos, you're correct. It's an odd one.. I can upload to a local test server running Express / Multer using your code... there must be something else going wrong...

Comment: Could it be that the server doesn't allow the "multipart/form-data" content type defined by the form-data object? What if I wanted to send an "application/pdf", what should I use?